# This Version Of ChromeDriver Only Supports 114

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

keep getting an error in console saying "selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114"

I downloaded chrome driver version 114 from the official website and set the executable path like this: service = Service(executable_path= r"C:\Python 3rd Party Installs\Selenium Driver(s)\114\chromedriver.exe")

Still the same message.

It is saying this as well: Current browser version is 116.0.5845.96 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Why is it running chrome 116 when I clearly specified the path to chrome driver 114?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the v114 Chrome Driver, which then tries to find and run Chrome, and the driver is telling you that

1. it only supports the v114 Chrome *browser* (implying that the version of the Chrome browser found by the driver is wrong for the driver), and
2. the version of the Chrome *browser* you have installed that the driver found is v116.

So you need to either get the v116 Chrome Driver or downgrade your Chrome browser from v116 to v114.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade your selenium to 4.11.0
no need of WebDriverManager,
Selenium Manager will handle all the matching browser drivers

Comment: The latest 4.12.0 also works for me.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using selenide library update it also to the latest version 6.17.1